# When I launch my macOS there running so many interfaces

Tags: macos, network

When my Mac started, I check my interfaces:

```
$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether a0:99:9b:17:50:07 
    inet6 fe80::cd8:2bd4:f767:a6ed%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5 
    inet 192.168.2.228 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c1 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 7 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 02:99:9b:17:50:07 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ba:2f:ce:01:6e:14 
    inet6 fe80::b82f:ceff:fe01:6e14%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether ba:2f:ce:01:6e:14 
    inet6 fe80::b82f:ceff:fe01:6e14%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::5e2a:55ee:b7dc:1b30%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::62d2:7e57:5727:90c8%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xd 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

in the beginning, I only use `lo0, en0`, maybe `en1` and `en2`. I some times install the VMware Fusion and docker and other things. I don't know why there get some many interfaces out, when I launched my Mac there will start so many interfaces, this is a waste of the computing resources, how to delete them or stop them?

Comment: How are you measuring waste of resources? It’s extremely unlikely dozens of interfaces would do anything to performance and everything you list looks perfectly normal with en1 and en2 inactive and the rest needed for minimal functions of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to get rid of your active interfaces, obviously, because they are active, meaning you are using them.

Inactive interfaces use up so little resources that it is not worth deleting them, especially since they will just have to be created again when you need them. They use a tiny bit of memory and that is it; they have no impact on performance.

Docker and VMware both create a lot of interfaces so they can use a separate, private, local network for their virtual machines, but they can get created by other software, too.